# MySQL Preference Pane control for MySQL installed via Homebrew

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I have installed MySQL via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/): `brew install mysql`. I'd like to get the MySQL preference pane hooked up to my installation of MySQL through homebrew. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You might get a better audience over at http://superuser.com - it's more geared to ports and MySQL and yes, homebrew is a program to help port things to mac, but to MySql and the preference panel are general to all OS and not mac-specific.

Comment: I agree that you might want to try this question over at SU.  Also, consider installing MAMP (http://www.mamp.info/) instead -- it's a "friendlier" way to get MySQL running on your Mac (along with Apache and PHP).

Comment: @Austin I will not be using MAMP as I do not need apache and php. I just need MySQL.

Comment: You could just think of it as "updating" Apache and PHP, since your Mac comes with both anyway.  You could be rocking a working MySQL installation in less than five minutes.  Up to you, though.

Answer (score 2):

See [my answer to your question at superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/413814/121764).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you can't get the MySQL Preference Pane via homebrew.  But if you download the 64-bit DMG file from [MySQL's community server download page](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/), it includes an installer, preference pane, and startup script.

See also the answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317614/getting-mysql-work-on-osx-10-7-lion), about installing MySQL on Lion.